# Airflow task instance stuck in retry mode

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

```
We are running airflow version 1.9 in celery executor mode. Our task instances are stuck in retry mode. When the job fails, the task instance retries. After that it tries to run the task and then fall back to new retry time.
```

First state:

```
Task is not ready for retry yet but will be retried automatically. Current date is 2018-08-28T03:46:53.101483 and task will be retried at 2018-08-28T03:47:25.463271.
```

After some time:

```
All dependencies are met but the task instance is not running. In most cases this just means that the task will probably be scheduled soon unless:
- The scheduler is down or under heavy load

If this task instance does not start soon please contact your Airflow administrator for assistance
```

After some time: it again went into retry mode.

Task is not ready for retry yet but will be retried automatically. Current date is 2018-08-28T03:51:48.322424 and task will be retried at 2018-08-28T03:52:57.893430.

This is happening for all dags. We created a test dag and tried to get logs for both scheduler and worker logs.

```
from datetime import *
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Pramiti',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

dag = DAG('airflow-examples.test_failed_dag_v2', description='Failed DAG',
          schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *',
          start_date=datetime(2018, 9, 7), default_args=default_args)

b = BashOperator(
    task_id="ls_command",
    bash_command="mdr",
    dag=dag
)
```

[Task Logs](http://pasted.co/777e5538)

[Scheduler Logs](http://pasted.co/efe6df76)

[Worker Logs](http://pasted.co/a7645d9c)

Comment: If the job keeps failing then I would expect it to continue to retry... Is your issue that the task always fails?

Comment: So the first time the task fails, the job goes in retry mode. Then it never get queued and running. Always there is up_for_retry state.

Comment: Having same issue, looks to me like a bug in Airflow, wondering if things are better with Airflow 1.10

Comment: Can you paste the dag file and task logs for the mentioned task

Comment: @SreenathKamath I have added logs. in the edit. Please check.

Comment: @pg20 I think its working as expected. If you see the task logs it has a log entry like 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Starting attempt 2 of 4
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: This means the second retry was done and the incremented next retry time you see might be for the third attempt

Comment: Yes I share you the logs of second attempt, but if you see, the task instance should retry immediately, 
The task started to check retry dependency at [2018-09-11 03:42:48,534]
but ran at [2018-09-11 06:27:36,590]. Why so ?